# Fail to install py-rrdtool on RedHat

Tags: python, redhat, rrdtool

I on RHEL6 with Python 2.6 and need to install rrdtool with python. I have to upload and install packages manually as network admin blocks yum and pip outgoing traffic for security reason. During installation I encounter missing error missing rrdtoolmodule.c, where can I locate the file? or I missing something?

```
[user@host ~]$ sudo pip install py-rrdtool-1.0b1.tar.gz
[sudo] password for user: 
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
Processing ./py-rrdtool-1.0b1.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: py-rrdtool
  Running setup.py install for py-rrdtool
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-a5tFI5-build/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-krfsUz-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6
    copying rrdtool.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6
    running build_ext
    building '_rrdtool' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/src
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c src/_rrdtoolmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/src/_rrdtoolmodule.o
    src/_rrdtoolmodule.c:34:17: error: rrd.h: No such file or directory
    In file included from src/rrd_extra.h:37,
                     from src/_rrdtoolmodule.c:35:
    src/rrd_format.h:59: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘rrd_value_t’
    src/rrd_format.h:295: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘rrd_value_t’
    src/_rrdtoolmodule.c: In function ‘PyRRD_create’:
    src/_rrdtoolmodule.c:93: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘rrd_create’
    src/_rrdtoolmodule.c:94: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘rrd_get_error’
    src/_rrdtoolmodule.c:94: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘PyErr_SetString’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
    /usr/include/python2.6/pyerrors.h:78: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
    src/_rrdtoolmodule.c:95: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘rrd_clear_error’
    src/_rrdtoolmodule.c: In function ‘PyRRD_update’:
    src/_rrdtoolmodule.c:122: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘rrd_update’
    src/_rrdtoolmodule.c:123: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘PyErr_SetString’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
    /usr/include/python2.6/pyerrors.h:78: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
    src/_rrdtoolmodule.c: In function ‘PyRRD_fetch’:
    src/_rrdtoolmodule.c:145: error: ‘rrd_value_t’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    src/_rrdtoolmodule.c:145: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
    src/_rrdtoolmodule.c:145: error: for each function it appears in.)
    src/_rrdtoolmodule.c:145: error: ‘data’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    src/_rrdtoolmodule.c:145: error: ‘datai’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    src/_rrdtoolmodule.c:145: warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect
    src/_rrdtoolmodule.c:154: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘rrd_fetch’
    src/_rrdtoolmodule.c:156: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘PyErr_SetString’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
    /usr/include/python2.6/pyerrors.h:78: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
    src/_rrdtoolmodule.c:165: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘dv’
    src/_rrdtoolmodule.c:191: error: ‘dv’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    src/_rrdtoolmodule.c: In function ‘PyRRD_graph’:
    src/_rrdtoolmodule.c:245: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘rrd_graph’
    src/_rrdtoolmodule.c:247: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘PyErr_SetString’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
    /usr/include/python2.6/pyerrors.h:78: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
    src/_rrdtoolmodule.c: In function ‘PyRRD_tune’:
    src/_rrdtoolmodule.c:297: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘rrd_tune’
    src/_rrdtoolmodule.c:298: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘PyErr_SetString’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
    /usr/include/python2.6/pyerrors.h:78: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
    src/_rrdtoolmodule.c: In function ‘PyRRD_last’:
    src/_rrdtoolmodule.c:324: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘rrd_last’
    src/_rrdtoolmodule.c:325: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘PyErr_SetString’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
    /usr/include/python2.6/pyerrors.h:78: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
    src/_rrdtoolmodule.c: In function ‘PyRRD_resize’:
    src/_rrdtoolmodule.c:350: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘rrd_resize’
    src/_rrdtoolmodule.c:351: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘PyErr_SetString’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
    /usr/include/python2.6/pyerrors.h:78: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
    src/_rrdtoolmodule.c: In function ‘PyRRD_info’:
    src/_rrdtoolmodule.c:380: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘PyErr_SetString’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
    /usr/include/python2.6/pyerrors.h:78: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
    src/_rrdtoolmodule.c:423: error: ‘unival’ has no member named ‘u_val’
    src/_rrdtoolmodule.c:423: error: ‘unival’ has no member named ‘u_val’
    src/_rrdtoolmodule.c:423: error: ‘unival’ has no member named ‘u_val’
    src/_rrdtoolmodule.c:423: error: ‘unival’ has no member named ‘u_val’
    src/_rrdtoolmodule.c:423: error: ‘unival’ has no member named ‘u_val’
    src/_rrdtoolmodule.c:423: error: ‘unival’ has no member named ‘u_val’
    src/_rrdtoolmodule.c:424: error: ‘unival’ has no member named ‘u_val’
    src/_rrdtoolmodule.c:424: error: ‘unival’ has no member named ‘u_val’
    src/_rrdtoolmodule.c:424: error: ‘unival’ has no member named ‘u_val’
    src/_rrdtoolmodule.c:424: error: ‘unival’ has no member named ‘u_val’
    src/_rrdtoolmodule.c:424: error: ‘unival’ has no member named ‘u_val’
    src/_rrdtoolmodule.c:424: error: ‘unival’ has no member named ‘u_val’
    src/_rrdtoolmodule.c:426: error: ‘unival’ has no member named ‘u_val’
    src/_rrdtoolmodule.c:426: error: ‘unival’ has no member named ‘u_val’
    src/_rrdtoolmodule.c:426: error: ‘unival’ has no member named ‘u_val’
    src/_rrdtoolmodule.c:426: error: ‘unival’ has no member named ‘u_val’
    src/_rrdtoolmodule.c:426: error: ‘unival’ has no member named ‘u_val’
    src/_rrdtoolmodule.c:426: error: ‘unival’ has no member named ‘u_val’
    src/_rrdtoolmodule.c:443: error: ‘unival’ has no member named ‘u_val’
    src/_rrdtoolmodule.c:443: error: ‘unival’ has no member named ‘u_val’
    src/_rrdtoolmodule.c:443: error: ‘unival’ has no member named ‘u_val’
    src/_rrdtoolmodule.c:443: error: ‘unival’ has no member named ‘u_val’
    src/_rrdtoolmodule.c:443: error: ‘unival’ has no member named ‘u_val’
    src/_rrdtoolmodule.c:443: error: ‘unival’ has no member named ‘u_val’
    src/_rrdtoolmodule.c:455: error: ‘unival’ has no member named ‘u_val’
    src/_rrdtoolmodule.c:455: error: ‘unival’ has no member named ‘u_val’
    src/_rrdtoolmodule.c:455: error: ‘unival’ has no member named ‘u_val’
    src/_rrdtoolmodule.c:455: error: ‘unival’ has no member named ‘u_val’
    src/_rrdtoolmodule.c:455: error: ‘unival’ has no member named ‘u_val’
    src/_rrdtoolmodule.c:455: error: ‘unival’ has no member named ‘u_val’
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-a5tFI5-build/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-krfsUz-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-a5tFI5-build
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manually download and install package from http://rpm.pbone.net

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely trying to compile a version of the rrdtool bindings created for a more recent version of rrdtool. Since rrdtool has changed over time, you may want to make sure to use the bindings matching with the version of rrdtool you are using or visa versa.